# How to get file modified date of a file with PowerShell?

Tags: 2013, powershell

I have a custom file customstyle.css in my site collestion's style library. How can I get this file's last modified date into a variable in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
$site = "https://sitecollectionurl"

#path of your css file
$sourcefile = "/style library/customstyle.css"

$web = Get-SPWeb $site

$file = $web.GetFile($site + $sourcefile)

$listItem = $file.ListItemAllFields

$modified = $listItem["Modified"]

write-host $modified
```

Comment: Thanks. I hvae to use the full url for GetFile but now it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
$FileURL = "http://something.com/...../customstyle.css"
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($FileURL)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$item = $web.GetListItem($FileURL)
$modified = $item["Modified"]
Write-Host $item.Name was modified on $modified

$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```